# Deleting the selected date partition in AWS Glue ETL Job

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have set up the data pipeline using AWS Glue Job (pySpark). The job is triggered from lambda function and after doing the relationalize, it writes the parquet files to the date partition.
There are times when I'm reprocessing the same date partition and would like to delete the previously written files before writing new ones. Is there a way to get the date partition within the job so that previously written files can be deleted first?

I know glue job maintains the date partition somewhere because when I call the glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options() it gets the partitionkeys correctly. I need to know which date partition the job is currently operating on to delete the files.  Thank you for your help. RF

Comment: Can you post your pyspark script here?

Comment: Here is the Glue ETL code that I'm using. I want to be able to delete the files in date partition if it already exists and then call the following write: rootDataSink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": rootPath, "partitionKeys": ["date"]}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")

Answer (score 0):

Currently AWS Glue doesn't support 'overwrite' mode but they are working on this feature.

As a workaround you can convert DynamicFrame object to spark's DataFrame and write it using spark instead of Glue. Example :

```
dynamic_frame.toDF()
  .write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("parquet")
  .partitionBy("date_col")
  .save(output_dir)
```

This will overwrite the files in provided partition and you need not worry about cleaning the partition explicitly.